# App crashes when drawing the background - null pointer exception

Tags: android, performance, android-canvas, android-image

Sometimes when I test my APP I get the null pointer exception error in the line mentioned below. The logcat and the code is given below. Kindly help me to resolve this error.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(backgoundImage, 0, 0  , null);
```

When the app crashes the I checked the size of the image to check whether the variable-backgoundImage is null. It shows the size correctly. I doubt the logic involved in canvas.

### Code:

```
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      Log.i("Notice", "In run of mybringback");  
        if(backgoundImage == null){ 
            try {Log.i("DragDrop", "backgoundImage is null.. In run of mybringback.. getting the image of background.."); 
                backgoundImage = getAssetImage(getApplicationContext(),"backgroundhomepage");  
                System.gc();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
            Log.i("DragDrop", "backgoundImage.getHeight() ;" + backgoundImage.getHeight());     

        ourHolder = getHolder();
        while (isRunning) {
//          Log.i("DragDrop", "ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()" +  ourHolder.getSurface().isValid() );
            if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            } 
            canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();    
            screenCenterX = dWidth / 2;
            screenCenterY = dHeight / 2;  
            canvas.drawBitmap(backgoundImage, 0, 0  , null);   
            if (imagePublishDone) {
                moveImageInEllipticalPath();
            } else {
                initialImagePublish();
            }

            centreReached = false;
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
```

### LogCat :

```
07-08 09:42:07.639: I/DragDrop(30560): In Resume drag drop
07-08 09:42:07.659: I/mybringback(30560): In resume of mybringback
07-08 09:42:07.669: I/DragDrop(30560): backgoundImage.getHeight() ;320
07-08 09:42:07.669: W/dalvikvm(30560): threadid=12: thread eiting with uncaught eception (group=0
07-08 09:42:07.669: E/AndroidRuntime(30560): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1090
07-08 09:42:07.669: E/AndroidRuntime(30560): java.lang.NullPointerEception
07-08 09:42:07.669: E/AndroidRuntime(30560): at com.eample.funandlearn.DragDrop$MyBringBackSurface.run(DragDrop.java:642)
07-08 09:42:07.669: E/AndroidRuntime(30560): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-08 09:42:07.719: I/mybringback(30560): In Pause of mybringback
```

Comment: check if backgroundimage is null. your `backgroundimage` is null.

Comment: I checked it. If it is null I am refreshing the variablebackgroundimage . Also I double checked the variable by checking the size.  logcat for that -  07-08 09:42:07.669: I/DragDrop(30560): backgoundImage.getHeight() ;320

Comment: `canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas()` your canvas is initialized here. so the other option is your bitmap is null. Also this should be removed `System.gc()`. Never do this.

Comment: but by bitmap is not null. Do I need to check and refresh the bitmap variable backgroundimage before canvas.drawBitmap(backgoundImage, 0, 0  , null);

Comment: check if your canvas is not null. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/graphics/Canvas.java#Canvas.drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%2Cfloat%2Cfloat%2Candroid.graphics.Paint%29. source code for reference. i still think your backgroundimage is null

Comment: I have confirmed the null in backgroundimage before drawing in canvas. Is it possible if the variable backgroundimage  set to null after initializing the canvas ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33060/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-iappmaker)

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this line and check.
Log.i("DragDrop", "backgoundImage.getHeight() ;" + backgoundImage.getHeight());